# Unity (C#) - SQLite3 database doesn't work on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite in a Unity game, and it works as expected when I build it for PC, but it doesn't work when I install the game on my Android phone.

```
int highscore;
int rows;

void Start () {
    string connection = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/flappy.db";

    IDbConnection dbconnection;
    dbconnection = new SqliteConnection(connection);
    dbconnection.Open();
    //After this line, nothing else is executed

    IDbCommand dbcommand = dbconnection.CreateCommand();

    dbcommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS highscore (score INTEGER)";
    dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dbcommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM highscore";
    rows = Convert.ToInt32(dbcommand.ExecuteScalar());

    if (rows == 0) {
        dbcommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO highscore VALUES (0)";
        dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        highscore = 0;
    }
    else {
        dbcommand.CommandText = "SELECT score FROM highscore";
        highscore = Convert.ToInt32(dbcommand.ExecuteScalar());
    }

    dbcommand.Dispose();
    dbcommand = null;
    dbconnection.Close();
    dbconnection = null;

    GetComponent<Text>().text = "Highscore: " + highscore.ToString();
}
```

This piece of code creates the database if it doesn't exist, creates the table if it doesn't exist, inserts a row if there is none, and sets the text of a UI element to the highscore value returned from the database.

On PC it shows "Highscore: 0" (or any other value). However, on Android it shows nothing. I would expect to see at least "Highscore: ", but that's not the case. Why is the value not being retrieved from the database on Android?

EDIT: After debugging for a while, I found that the last line executed in the Start() function is "dbconnection.Open();". After this, nothing else is executed. Isn't SQLite supposed to create the database when you connect to a database that doesn't exist?